# Jquery - show intersection of two arrays as percentage

Tags: jquery, intersection

I have a textarea for keywords and a textarea for a summary.  I have a function that derives keywords from each.  I want to compare the two lists of keywords and show a percentage of those that match.  Is this possible using Jquery?

Comment: You can do anything you want, jQuery/JavaScript is Turing-complete. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have:

```
var a1 = ["cat", "dog", "fish"];
var a2 = ["dog", "monkey", "cat", "horse"];

var matches = 0;
$.each(a1, function(i, a1val){
  if($.inArray(a1val, a2)) matches++;
});
var maxn = Math.max(a1.length, a2.length);
var percent = matches/maxn * 100;

alert(parseInt(percent, 10) + "% of similarity");
```

Comment: This looks great but I get strange results when trying this. I populate a1 and a2 from another function and get matches where there are none.  Even if I change the data in a1 and a2 by hand, I get false matches.  I must not be doing it right.

Comment: Some of the inconsistencies from this are removed by modifying this:

     if($.inArray(a1val, a2)) matches++;

to:

     if($.inArray(a1val, a2)>-1) matches++;

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write your own Javascript to do it, there's a jQuery plugin ([Rich Array](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/rich-array)) that provides array utility functions, one of which is an intersection function.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually take a look at the jQuery utility functions, I'm thinking that the function `inArray()` might be able to handle a lot of the heavy lifting.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

If you post some code I'm sure someone would take a crack at it even :)